# Codeigniter change session id

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a problem. On my website, users can log in and do some orders. But I wanna change my session_id after succesful order, but without logout. There is a problem when I change session_id, users are automatically log out. I am using framework codeigniter. How can I change it?
Thank you for replies

Comment: CodeIgniter will update the session (regenerate the session ID) every 300 seconds by default. However, in order to update the session manually, you need to extend the Session library and write your needed functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the php function

```
session_regenerate_id();
```

[check the about link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php)

Comment: session_regenerate_id(); It doesnt work for me. It doesnt change my session_id

Comment: CodeIgniter has their own session implementation, using this does not help when you are using the CI session library.